# Integrate google+ in iphone?

Tags: iphone

Is it possibele to share data on google plus from the application same as facebook and twitter.?

Please help me for this query

Comment: It appears you have done no research on this topic, so I have down voted and voted to close. [Google Plus API iPhone](http://bit.ly/zG0SYh)

Comment: I have dont but due to net issue I am not able to search properly..

Comment: From your application, from a other application, and what have tried so far ?

Comment: No need to be rude.  Some people don't speak English as well as native speakers and can't be expected to think of appropriate search terms all the time.

Answer (score 2):

No. There is a [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/) but it is read-only.